# Add value in middleware SlimV3

Tags: php, slim, middleware, psr-7

Im new in SLimV3, And I Want to use the middleWare to create Json Output.

My code is:
Controller:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
....
    $out['message'] = "ok";
    $out['code'] = 0;
    $response->withJson($out);
  }
```

my route:

```
  $app->get('/foo', App\Action\Foo::class)->add(new foo\Middleware());
```

my middleware

```
class Middleware{

  public function __invoke(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response,$next) {
    $started = microtime(true);
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $json = json_decode( (string) $response->getBody(),true);
    $json['execution_time'] = microtime(true) - $started;
    $newResponse = $response->withJson($json);
    return $newResponse;
  }
}
```

my Output is Ok,

```
{
  "message": "ok",
  "code": 0,
  "execution_time": 0.44862484931946
}
```

but I don't like to create Json in my controller, Json Decode in middleware, and again `$newResponse = $response->withJson($json);`. I'd like to read Response and create the response in middleware, or read the status code and create the custom Response.
Can I Do It ?

Comment: So you want to provide the data in the controller but json decode it inside the middleware after the controller got executed?

Comment: @jmattheis exactly, I'd like to pass Response to Middleware and the middleware evaluate Response ( 200, 404, 500 ) and create the right Json Response. is it a good practice about middleware? Thanks !

Comment: I dont this this is a good practice, this should all be done inside the route.

Comment: @jmattheis What Can I handle with middleware? I can handle Authentication, but I Read that I can use middleware for Error Handling. how Can I do it if The exception is inside Controller?

Comment: There are error handler inside slim see [documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/error.html)

Comment: @jmattheisyes I know, error handler is only an example about middleware